# Write a function or regular expression that will split string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

i have in sql table values in this way:

```
Id GameId GameSupplierId
1  1      NULL
2  2      NULL
3  3      1
4  3      2
5  3      3
```

What i want is to filter in sql procedure by GameId and if there is GameSupplierId by supplier too. I will get string from my web page in format GameID ; GameSupplierId. For example:

```
1; NULL
2; NULL
```

or if there is GameSupplier too

```
3;1
3;1,2
```

Also i want to have multiple choice for example like this:

```
1,2,3;1,2
```

In my sql query i will then filter like `WHERE @GameID = Table.GameID (and also to check @GameSupplierId IN (,,,))`

Comment: "I want ..." is not meeting what is expected of a question here at StackOverflow. Please demonstrate your own research efforts. E.g. show coding attempts and explain how their result does not satisfy you. (Downvote not by me though.) Questions like this, not asking for help with a specific problem and instead just expecting a coded solution, are too broad.

Comment: Also, I think you need to look at your data structures and to returning better structured data from your web page.

Comment: Find a function that splits strings and split it on ';'. Add parentheses to the 2 elements and create a string (nvarchar) with IN. Use dynamic SQL to return your results. All in all, not a very simple thing though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your desired columns into `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY t.GameId, t.GameSuplierId
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    GameId INT,
    GameSuplierId INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    ID,
    GameId,
    GameSuplierId
)
VALUES
  (1,  1,      NULL)
, (2,  2,      NULL)
, (3,  3,      1)
, (4,  3,      2)
, (5,  3,      3)

SELECT 
*
FROM @table t
ORDER BY t.GameId, t.GameSuplierId
```